# What's the cheapest way to host hobby projects?

Tags: amazon-ec2, web-hosting, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

What's the best place to put your hobby web projects(the web app itself, not the code) ? Typically, the projects are such that:

a) I just want to test out an interesting idea without exploring the business angle to it, just to see how people take it.

b) I don't expect a lot of traffic

c) I don't want to scale immediately

d) I don't want to be tied down to one technology(I want to do different projects to get familiar with various web stacks, langs and libs)

Google app engine seems very restrictive for such exploratory stuff ... Restrictions like no outbound request can go beyond 10 seconds and every request has to return with 30 seconds, etc. annoy me, I know they are needed for scale, but I would like them to be optional.

Amazon EC2 micro nodes are free for a year. But they ask for credit card information which I am not sure if I want to give away when I'm not paying initially.

What other free/cheap alternatives do I have?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for hosting on a cloud?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon Free Usage Tier - http://aws.amazon.com/free/
Works well for your purpose!

Comment: Can only use it for 1 year

Answer (score 6):

Host at home. Use dyndnsto redirect a public real domain to your local changing ip address. Done.

Comment: I used to do this for years.

Answer (score 1):

Find yourself a cheap VPS. Linode, prgmr.com, whatever.